# How to show result of QR code Scanner into other Activity?

Tags: android

I am trying to make an app in which i want to add the functionality of QR code scanning and show the result in other Activity and then send the result to server.
I am new in android so please help me solve this problem...
Thanks in advance

Comment: use StartActivityForResult to get barcode from another activity.

Comment: If you are new to Android, you'd better start learning how to launch a new activity first.

Comment: I don't see any problem!

Answer (score 0):

There are many articles on this. You can search. This is post in [AndroidHive](https://www.androidhive.info/2017/08/android-barcode-scanner-using-google-mobile-vision-building-movie-tickets-app/) a typical example